# LuxBlend light groups

Tags: rendering, mesh, add-on, light, luxrender-render-engine

I just installed LuxBlend, LuxRender for Blender, in order to test it, and I'm very new to using it. I made a simple scene with a couple of mesh lights "plane objects", and assigned emitting materials to them. I'm trying to get two Light Groups, one for each mesh light, but it looks like something is missing. The Light Groups panel in Render Layers tab is empty. I tried to add it in the light material with no luck, for light materials, I chose Null, for material type, and checked LuxRender Light Emission check box, "as I've seen in a tutorial." There's a tutorial on the Luxrender website that explains how to do it, but I'm sure it's for a different version, because there's a Material Type called "Light", which makes sense. Why choose "Null" for a light? But in the version I have, there's no such material type! I'm using Blender 2.77a, LuxBlend 27.
[image]

[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question... but you do have Lux selected as your renderer in the pull-down at the top of the screen, right?

Comment: @Matt, Yes, otherwise I wouldn't have the materials and all other panels in that I attached in my question.

Comment: Okay, cool. I wasn't sure if that's why they showed up, or if they were just part of the plugin.

Comment: I uninstalled the version I had, reinstalling the experimental version, just to check if this is a bug in the version I have, or something I'm doing wrong, or I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with this issue, I found out this is a bug. I uninstalled Luxrender, removed the add-on from Blender, restarted my machine and installed a different version. Using Luxrender 1.6 test version No OpenCL, I have the Light Groups available in Render Layers panel. The Materials Panel preview is still black. I couldn't find a Group Node (maybe just because I'm unfamiliar with Lux), but if I don't use Nodes, I can create Light Groups in Render Layers panel and assign light materials to the Light Groups.

Comment: Support for Group Nodes is not implemented in LuxBlend yet (I don't know if it's already possible with Blender's Python API, I fear not).
If your material preview is black, check Blender's console after a fresh start, there are probably errors importing the pylux/pyluxcore modules. Ask in the Lux forums for further help in that case, and make sure Blender and Lux are the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click "Add LuxRender Material Node Tree" in your material. Blender is currently trying to cram the data from the original Blender material into a LuxRender material, and that doesn't work very well.

Once you click that, it should start making more sense.
You can find more information [here](http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxBlend_Node_Editor).

[image]

Comment: When I click "Add LuxRender Material Node Tree." All the panels in the Material tab disappear except for Preview and Emission. Nothing shows up in the Node Editor!

Comment: It doesn't look like the image I just added?

Comment: Yes it does, but clicking the drop down menu beside in Light Emission does nothing. How can I use this?

Comment: I'll be out for a few hours. In the meantime, make sure "Use Nodes" is checked and press the "home" key and.or the "period"  on the number pad while you're hovering over the node editor to zoom to any nodes that are present, just to make sure.

Comment: ...make sure that you're scrolled all the way down. Sometimes when you expand panels, they go off the screen without telling you.

Comment: It works, I can see the node, I had to check an icon that looks like the Material icon in the Node Editor, called "LuxRender Material Node", but I still can't make light groups, the "LuxRender Light Groups" panel in the Render Layers tab is still empty.

Comment: Ok, so I uninstalled Luxrender, removed the addon from Blender, redownloaded the test version, Luxrender 1.6 and restarted my Windows, and I can see the Light Groups, so this was a bug, I will delete this question tomorrow.

Comment: No need to delete the question. Others also need to know that it's a bug, not a user error. You should just add an answer that explains that it's a bug, and then accept it.